# Parsin JSON information - Android studio

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

i am currently trying to parse a simple `JSON` information but can't figure out the `JSON` object and array part... I'm trying to extract from this `JSON`(below) the app_time and postcode + address.  Can anyone give me a solution about my "`extractFeatureFromJson`()", sorry about the formatting it's my first post here.

```
{
"data": [
{
"id": 24256,
"app_time": 1904280242,
"addresses": [
{
"id": 1,
"postcode": "9000",
"address": "Street:Street, City: City, Country: Country"
}
],
"comments": [
{
"id": 1,
"comment": "Comment",
"created_at": 234234234
}
]
}
]
}


public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String _URL = "https://.......com/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ScheduleAsyncTask task = new ScheduleAsyncTask();
    task.execute();
}

private void updateUi(Event job) {

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    titleTextView.setText(getDateString(job.time));

    TextView dateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
    dateTextView.setText(job.address);
}

private String getDateString(long timeInMilliseconds) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    return formatter.format(timeInMilliseconds);
}





private class ScheduleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Event> {

    @Override
    protected Event doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // Create URL object
        URL url = createUrl(_URL);

        // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        String jsonResponse = "";
        try {
            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle the IOException
        }
        Event jobs = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);


        return jobs;

    }




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Event job) {
        if (job == null) {
            return;
        }

        updateUi(job);
    }

    /**
     * Returns new URL object from the given string URL.
     */
    private URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error with creating URL", exception);
            return null;
        }
        return url;
    }



    private String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Application", ".....");
            urlConnection.connect();
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the exception
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                // function must handle java.io.IOException here
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    private String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }



    private Event extractFeatureFromJson(String scheduleJSON) {
        try {
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(scheduleJSON);
            JSONArray featureArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("comments");

            // If there are results in the features array

                // Extract out the first feature 
                JSONObject firstFeature = featureArray.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject properties = firstFeature.getJSONObject("comment");

                // Extract out the time address values
                String address = properties.getString("address");
                long time = properties.getLong("app_time");


                // Create a new {@link Event} object
                return new Event(address, time);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing the JSON results", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your json structure, data is json array and so is addresses and comments, so you have to work your way down to those json arrays and finally json objects.

One way to understand json structure (objects and array is to format it and view it. Use online json formatters like https://jsonformatter.org/  or install plugins in notepad++ to format json.

***NOTE:*** I am not giving you full solution as it is for your own benefit so here is what you should do and add debugger points and system.out.println (Log.d in android) for understanding json object and array you traverse and learn yourself.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
JSONObject appTime = obj.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject(“app_time”);
JSONObject postal_code = obj.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray(“addresses”).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject(“postcode”);
```

You have to add appropriate null checks at each step to avoid NPE.

You can also use JSONObject’s methods to retrieve specific data type (getString, getLong, etc.)

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Thank you for the good answer @JRG, I am currently trying to learn and code at the same time and i need to finish this by Monday and any help would be deeply appreciated. 
Right now i'm struggling with - "Problem parsing the JSON results
                                                                               org.json.JSONException: Value 1504620000 at app_time of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject" 
I can't understand Value 1504620000 is an Int ok. the app_time in UNIX format and i am trying to pass it as long and doesn't this mean that i'm not reading it right?

Comment: private Event extractFeatureFromJson(String str) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
                JSONObject appTime = obj.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("app_time");

 long timeEvent = appTime.getLong("app_time");

Comment: That’s correct, you would have to know what are you extracting (int or long and whether the value will fit into the limits of datatype or go to wider data types) and use appropriate data type for conversion or use JSONObject methods like getString, getLong etc. here is link for more information. https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html I will add it to my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (scheduleJSON!= null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(scheduleJSON);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONArray data= jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

     // looping through All data
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject id = data.getJSONObject(id);
                            JSONObject app_time=data.getJSONObject(app_time);
                            String id = c.getString("id");

                            // Getting JSON Array node
JSONArray addresses=new JSONArray(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("addresses"));
JSONArray comments= new JSONArray(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("comments"));

}

    }catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());

    }
```